# SSIS to execute stored procedures asynchronously in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asynchronous, ssis

I am just starting to use the Enterprise version of SQL Server 2014. I am completely new to Integration Services and need to use it to call stored procedures asynchronously.

Is using SSIS different from using SQL Server Agent? I am aware of SQL jobs and agents to execute stored procedures asynchronously. Is there any other way to do it using SSIS?

What I really mean to ask is [Is there any other way to use SSIS for asynchrnous execution besides this?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541834/How-to-execute-multiple-long-running-SQL-Statement)
Also, Can I get guidance on how to start with it as I am completely raw with SSIS.

Comment: Googling "SSIS Tutorials" is a good way to get started.

Comment: Okay, Why has it been down-voted ? Broad category ? Wrong question ?

Comment: Probably because the question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: @TabAlleman:Ofcouse I did that. But looks like I am missing upon something. That looks completely irrelevant to what I am trying to do. Any link that you may think help someone who is completely new to this will do for me. Thanks.

Comment: What tutorial did you do that looked completely irrelevant?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/92e85b85-7e1b-49df-bad0-51c1590c7559/calling-each-stored-procedure-parallel-in-sql-job Like this says call SSIS,Now, I am not aware how do  I call SSIS. Also, not sure if that needs to be explicitiy done as some say SSIS taes care of that and is automated.

Comment: With SSIS, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150109/parallel-execution-of-stored-procedures-in-job-sql-server. The link has to say create different jobs and an agent which comes back to SQL agents. As far as I remember from what I read, there is some other way to do it as well without SQL agents and jobs if we are using SSIS.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you.  These links are to forum questions, and the answers in them assume that the reader already has some basic knowledge of SSIS.   How to call it.  What is a task.  What are Precedence Constraints.   You need to do some beginner's tutorials to get the basics of SSIS.   Then you will be able to understand the answers in the forums, including the one Benjamin gave to yours.

Comment: Thanks. I wll try to go back to it then. Just last question,please check the link I added to my post and let me know if this the only way or there are other that I need to look at,please? Thanks.@TabAlleman

Comment: Ok, no, that is not the only way to do it.   The way Benjamin suggested below is the way I would do it.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Sorry about adding unproductive question to the forum.Let me know if I need to delete it.

Comment: @TabAlleman: I have created those SQL tasks and wanted to call those in one of my stored procedures which otherwise was calling those stored procedures directly. Do you mind explaining how to do that,please? Thanks

Comment: Parallel execution is not the same as asynchronous execution. Which do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just create your tasks (such as Execute SQL Task which can invoke stored procedures) in parallel. Make sure the arrows don't lead into each other. SSIS will invoke the tasks simultaneously.

Comment: Does creating task has a specific meaning or you mean I shall just create procedures and executed them from a stored procedure and those will be execute asynchronously ?  (I am just trying to understand as it is not clear to me ) . Thanks.

Comment: In SSIS a package is composed of one or more tasks. There are many different kinds of tasks, one of which is the Exec SQL Task.

Comment: I have created those SQL tasks and wanted to call those in one of my stored procedures which otherwise was calling those stored procedures directly. Do you mind explaining how to do that,please? Thanks

Comment: While the Execute SQL Tasks will run in parallel, they *won't* be asynchronous. The Tasks won't terminate until the procedure calls finish